$A^3=A$, ${\alpha }^{T}{A}^{T}{A\alpha } \leq {\alpha }^{T}\alpha$ implies $A$ is symmetric?

Let $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ satisfies ${A}^{3} = A$; and for any $\alpha\in\Bbb R^n$, we have ${\alpha }^{T}{A}^{T}{A\alpha } \leq {\alpha }^{T}\alpha$, prove that  $A$ is symmetric.

My attempt: $|(A'-A)x|\leq 0$ for any $x$? it is not easy to estimate..
eigenvalues of $A$ is $0,\pm 1$, using Jordan carnonical form? How $|Ax|\leq |x|$ be used?

Try to show that the eigenspaces must be orthogonal.

$A$ is diagonalizable [min polynomial or other argument] and argue $A$ is normal since  sum of squared eigenvalues modulus equals frobenius norm; thus $A$ is real orthogonally diagonalizable, i.e. symmetric.

First, $A$ is diagonalizable, because its minimal polynomial divides $t^3 - t = t(t+1)(t-1)$ and hence splits into distinct linear factors.
It suffices to show that distinct eigenspaces are orthogonal. Suppose $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors with $Av = \lambda v$ and $Aw = \mu w$, and assume $v^T w \ne 0$; we would like to show $\lambda = \mu$. The matrix $B := I - A^T A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite ($\alpha^T B\alpha = \alpha^T \alpha - \alpha^T A^T A\alpha \ge 0$), so it satisfies a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$(v^T Bw)^2 \le (v^T Bv) (w^T Bw),$$
which works out to
$$ (1 - \lambda\mu)^2 c^2 \le (1 - \lambda^2)(1 - \mu^2), $$
where $c := \dfrac{v^T w}{|v| |w|} \ne 0$. Now since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, we must have either $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda^2 = 1$.

If $\lambda = 0$, then $0 < c^2 \le 1 - \mu^2$ gives $\mu^2 < 1$, so $\mu = 0$ (because $\mu$ is an eigenvalue).
If $\lambda^2 = 1$, then $(1 - \lambda\mu)^2 c^2 \le 0$ gives $1 - \lambda\mu = 0$, so $\mu = 1/\lambda = \lambda$.

In either case we have $\lambda = \mu$, so we are done.
(One can generalize this to complex matrices where instead of $A^3 = A$, we just assume that all nonzero eigenvalues have absolute value $1$ and obtain that $A$ is normal.)

Let's first consider that
\begin{equation}
A^{3} = A^{2}A \overset{task}{=} A \Rightarrow A^{2} = \mathbb{I}
\end{equation}
with $\mathbb{I}$ being the identity matrix. Since $A^{2} = \mathbb{I}$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(A^{2}\right)^{T} &= \mathbb{I}^{T} = \mathbb{I}\\
&= \left(AA\right)^{T} = A^{T}A^{T} = \left(A^{T}\right)^{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Let's consider now the products
\begin{align}
\mathbb{I}\,\mathbb{I} &= A^{2}\left(A^{T}\right)^{2} = AAA^{T}A^{T}\\
\mathbb{I}\,\mathbb{I} &= A^{2}A^{2} = AAAA\\
\mathbb{I}\,\mathbb{I} &= \left(A^{T}\right)^{2}\left(A^{T}\right)^{2} = A^{T}A^{T}A^{T}A^{T}
\end{align}
Obviously, these equations can only be fulfilled simultaneously if $A$ is symmetric

why the downvote?

This doesn't make any sense. $A^2=I$ is false, the final sentence doesn't follow, and you have not used ${\alpha }^{T}{A}^{T}{A\alpha } \leq {\alpha }^{T}\alpha$ anywhere.

please explain, why $A^2=\mathbb{I}$ does not follow from $A^{3} = A^{2}A \overset{task}{=} A$

If $A=0$ for example, $A^3=A$ but $A^2\ne I$

Moreover, $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $A^2 = I$, but clearly $A$ is not symmetric.
